# C++: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an ADT `class Set` that inherits the methods of its parent template `class SetInterface`.`I also have`class Song`and`class PlayList`, which essentially inherits the`corresponding `class Set` public members. I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from Song.cpp:7:0: Set.h:12:33: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token class Set : public SetInterface {.
```

I have seen threads with a similar issue and tried the following suggestions:

1. Checked to ensure that my include guards were spelled correctly
2. Including my files in the **.cpp** as opposed to the **.hpp** file
3. Including the class as opposed to using `#include "className.h"`
4. Using a circular include

However, I am still getting the same error, or it reappears for a different file. So, I decided to create my own post. Here's the code that I have for each file:

1. SetInterface.h

   ```
   #ifndef SET_INTERFACE_H_

   #define SET_INTERFACE_H_

   #include <vector>

   template<class ItemType>

   class SetInterface

   {

    public:
   ...
   }; // end SetfInterface

   #endif /* SET_INTERFACE_H_ */
   ```
2. Set.h

   ```
   #ifndef SET_H_

   #define SET_H_

   template <class ItemType>
   class Set : public SetInterface {

   private:

    static const int DEFAULT_SET_SIZE = 4; // for testing purposes we will keep the set small

    ItemType items_[DEFAULT_SET_SIZE]; // array of set items    
    int item_count_;                  // current count of set items

    int max_items_;                   // max capacity of the set

    int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;

   };

   #endif
   ```
3. Set.cpp

   ```
   #include "Set.h"
   #include "Song.h"

    template<class ItemType>
    class Set : SetInterface {
    public:
    ...
   };
   ```
4. Song.h

   ```
   #include <string>

   class Song {

   public:
   ...
   };
   ```
5. Song.cpp

   ```
   #include "Set.h"
   #include "Song.h"
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>
   //Default constructor for Song which initializes values
   Song::Song() {
     std::string title_;
     std::string author_;
     std::string album_;
    }
   ...
   }
   ```
6. Playlist.h

   ```
   class PlayList : public Set {
   public: 

     PlayList();

     PlayList(const Song& a_song);
     int getNumberOfSongs() const;

     bool isEmpty() const;

     bool addSong(const Song& new_song);

     bool removeSong(const Song& a_song);

     void clearPlayList();

     void displayPlayList() const;

    private: 

       Set<Song> playlist_;
   }
   ```
7. PlayList.cpp

   ```
   #include "Set.h"
   #include "Song.h"
   #include "PlayList.h"
   #include <iostream>

   template<class ItemType>
   class PlayList : public Set {
   public:
   ...
   }
   ```

   How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

Since `SetInterface` is a template class, you need to specify the template parameter when inheriting from it:

```
#ifndef SET_H_

#define SET_H_

template <class ItemType>
class Set : public SetInterface<ItemType> {

private:

 static const int DEFAULT_SET_SIZE = 4; // for testing purposes we will keep the set small

 ItemType items_[DEFAULT_SET_SIZE]; // array of set items    
 int item_count_;                  // current count of set items

 int max_items_;                   // max capacity of the set

 int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;

};

#endif
```